# Is there a way to restrict an AWS Cognito user or group (from a user pool) from accessing certain clients registered in the pool?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to restrict an AWS Cognito user or group (within a user pool) from accessing specific app clients registered with the pool.  It would be nice to be able to keep the same user base, but restrict individual clients.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you are trying to do or can you describe the situation where this is necessary?

Comment: I plan to add multiple API Gateway services secured using JWT, where each service is represented by a client app entry.  My hope was to assign groups or users to services they are allowed to access.  I didn't want a separate user pool for every app, and I don't see a way to secure access to apps in a user pool on a per-uses basis.  This is a big oversight IMHO.  I have a working POC in place, so all is well, but all users have access to all client apps in the pool.

Comment: I'm not still clear what you are trying to do. I'm assuming that you want one of your app to be sign up with google only and other app with sign up with facebook only...and like that. if that is your case, one thing that you can try is to create a custom sign up page for every app and giving only the required IDP option to log in for the user. For example, if you want the users of one of your app to signUp with only google account, you can create a custom signUp page for that app with a sign up with google button only.